# How do I get Swashbuckle to work in Asp.net Core 3.1 when using VersionByNamespaceConvention?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using VersionByNamespaceConvention. In Startup.cs in ConfigureServices I added:

```
        services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.Add(new VersionByNamespaceConvention());
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v2" });
        });
```

and in Configure

```
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "My API V2");
        });
```

In the root of the project I have folders v1 and v2 and under those I have a Controllers folder. The code of the controllers (v2 is identical to v1, except for the namespace and the return value).

```
namespace WebApitest.v1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "v1";
        }
    }
}
```

The api itself is working good, but Swagger rendering is not working as expected.

When opening https://localhost:44307/swagger/index.html it shows a dropdown in the top right corner showing "My API V1" and "My API V2" but the middle of the screen is showing

> Fetch error - undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json

This works if I only have controllers in the v1 version. But then it is showing the version number like in the image below, even though the version number here is already selected.

[image]

**The solution**

I added the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer v4.x and added the following code to ConfigureServices and now it's working as expected.

```
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o =>
        {
            o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
            o.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });
```

Comment: Could you share the code of your controllers?

Comment: @bmartins Added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `services.AddVersionedApiExplorer` and set `options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl=true` to tell swagger to replace the version in the controller route and configure the api version:

```
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o =>
{
      o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
      o.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});
```

Result:
[image]